# Android LongClickListener on ExpandableListView group items

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I created an ExpandableListView with the help of this tutorial: [link](http://blog.csdn.net/avenleft/article/details/7192972).
I understand the code more or less and been trying to set a longclicklistener on the groups.

There is a setOnChildClickListener on the child items already and I managed to set a longclicklistener on them:

```
exList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
              groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
              childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);
//[....]
 return false;
      }
  });
```

How can I set a longclicklistener on the group items?

I know the code is hard to read so I created a sample project and uploaded it to [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/lluR74Go/ExListView.html).
This has no onlongclicklistener on the childs, since this is almost the original from the above link.
I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Group items are a subset of all items, so the method above should be called in either case.  You'd then use getPackedPositionType as above to figure out if the selected item is a group, an item, or null.

The code for this would be:

```
exList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          int itemType = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id);

          if ( itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
              childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);
              groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);

              //do your per-item callback here
              return retVal; //true if we consumed the click, false if not

          } else if(itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
              groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
              //do your per-group callback here
              return retVal; //true if we consumed the click, false if not

          } else {
              // null item; we don't consume the click
              return false;
          }
  });
```

If it's a group, you'll use getPackedPositionGroup as above to get the group ID that is being long-pressed.  If it's an item, you'll use the combination of getPackedPositionGroup and getPackedPositionChild.

Comment: Wow. This was so easy. Thank you very much!

Comment: Wow....This normally implementation but perfectly working fine with group and child events of data access it for position.