# How can I set LongClick on group in ExpandableListView [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have a ExanpdableLisView, and I have to implement the methods setOnChildClickListener for the childs and the "LongClick" for the group/parent.

I have donde the childs one, but I don't know how to achive the LongClick.

This is the code for `setOnChildClickListener`

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                RosterEntry rentry = (RosterEntry) exListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
                final String selected = rentry.getName();
                //Change Toast to make the new functionality
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

But I have no idea how to do LongClick on Group/parent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android LongClickListener on ExpandableListView group items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950661/android-longclicklistener-on-expandablelistview-group-items)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For long click on either group or child views,

```
getExpandableListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    Override   
    public boolean onItemLongClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        long packedPosition = m_expandableListView.getExpandableListPosition(position);

        int itemType = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(packedPosition); 
        int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition);
        int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(packedPosition);


        /*  if group item clicked */
        if (itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
            //  ...
            onGroupLongClick(groupPosition);
        }

        /*  if child item clicked */
        else if (itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
            //  ...
            onChildLongClick(groupPosition, childPosition);
        }


        return false;
    }
});
```

Define the `onGroupLongClick()` and `onChildLongClick()` methods to do whatever you want.

Try this. This will work.

Comment: Do you know what the `id` parameter here represents? It's not the same value as you get from the `id` parameter in `OnChildClickListener.onChildClick()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the cleanest solution, but in your adapter you could in the getGroupView method register an onLongClick listener for each of the views when they are created.

```
public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if(converView == null)
     {
        View view = new View(context);
        view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v)
            {     
                //enter code here
            }
        });
     }

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @jonte , probably this can help me in a future, to have different "reactions" deppending on the group clicked, an have the main code more clean ^^. The answer of Zygoltelnit works perfect